# I am trying to create a formula to calculate the number of remaining full months left in the year from the closed date

Tags: formula, closedate

Example::

If close date is not this year, amount this year = 0

If close date is this year, amount this year = Setup cost + (Monthly amount x number of whole months between the close date and the end of the year)

Eg, if the setup was £10k, monthly amount £2k, and close date 14/7, the calculation would be: £10k + (£2k x 5) = £20k

And when we move into 2015, we need to ensure the calculation works as we move into the next year.

Answer (score 2):

The formula to return the number of whole months remaining in the year is just:

```
12 - MONTH(CloseDate)
```

and you can use the YEAR function to do the year matching part giving you a multiplier factor field of:

```
IF(YEAR(CloseDate) == YEAR(TODAY()), 12 - MONTH(CloseDate), 0)
```

(And of course you can incorporate the other values in that one formula or in a further formula field.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for ,because you have the answer itself.

But what I understood I am giving you a sample (not code i.e. not working code).

Let me know in case of any queries or correct me If I am wrong

> ```
>     int totalAmount=0; 
>     if(closeddate.Year==DateTime.Now.Year)    
>     {
>        do{
>           int reaminingMonth=12-ClosedDate.Month;
>           totalAmount=totalAmount+SetupCost+(monthly_amount* reaminingMonth);
>         }
>        while(DateTime.Now.Year<year_you_want)     
>     } 
>     else 
>    {//do what you want  }
> ```